# Check if all items in a list are a specific number in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I'm learning prolog. I'm trying to write a small program that checks if all entries in a given list are 1.

```
singleton([Head|Tail]) :- 
    Head = 1,
    singleton(Tail).
```

The program returns false when I pass the list [1,1]. Why?

Comment: Because there is no information about what to do when Tail becomes `[]`. The default is then to fail. You need to add: `singleton([]).`

Comment: do I have to specify that with every function I write?

Comment: "with every predicate", not "with every function". But basically yes. If you recurse down the list, going from `[A|As]` to `As`, which becomes the `[A|As]` of the new context when the recursive call is made ... you have to say what when happens if there is no `A` any longer ... Otherwise Prolog will have an `[]` in the hand and there will be nothing to match it, because `[A|As]` cannot be the same as `[]`.

Comment: You never match it with the *empty* list, so eventually you recurse on the empty list and ths will fail.

Comment: When I work in Java, I always reflect on "hat does this code compile to"? When I work in Prolog (or Clojure, though recently I haven't) I don't think like that, I always consider all the structures to behave exactly like they are written down in the editor: graphs of stringy things to be analyzed. This includes code itself. Difficult to explain, but it's much more how programming should be like than faffing around with various details in C.

Comment: @HaiseSasaki Please do not forget to accept an answer if it solves your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You did not define that the empty list satisfies `singleton/1` as well. If you call `singleton([1, 1])`. then the recursion will call `singleton([1])` and when processing that, it will call `singleton([])`. Since `singleton([])` fails, this thus means that `singleton([1])` will fail, and therefore `singleton([1,1])`.

You thus can use:

```
singleton([]).
singleton([1|Tail]) :- 
    singleton(Tail).
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight correction to your code:

```
singleton([]).
singleton([Head|Tail]) :- 
Head = 1,
singleton(Tail).

trace, (singleton([1,1,1])).
 Call:singleton([1, 1, 1])
 Call:1=1
 Exit:1=1
 Call:singleton([1, 1])
 Call:1=1
 Exit:1=1
 Call:singleton([1])
 Call:1=1
 Exit:1=1
 Call:singleton([])
 Exit:singleton([])
 Exit:singleton([1])
 Exit:singleton([1, 1])
 Exit:singleton([1, 1, 1])
1true
```